# Using Google Maps APIs (or any other map services) how can I point the addresses on map that are near to particular address?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, bing-maps

I have a database with vendors  addresses including geocodes and a one particular address "A" with geocode. I want to display all the vendor address which are nearby (in x radius) to address "A" on map in the web browser.

What are the different options like google maps api or any other service available that can help me achieve this?

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

You may calculate the distance to each vendor by using [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#spherical) and create markers when the distance is <= x

A faster approach would be to use a FusionTable  to store the data. You would be able to use a FusionTableLayer to draw the markers with a simple `WHERE`-clause:

```
ST_INTERSECTS(columnWithVendorLatLng,
              CIRCLE(LATLNG(addressLatitude, addressLongitude),desiredRadius))
```